# How to perform $elemMatch on array when performing $lookup aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Facing an issue. Not sure how to make the query for needed data.

For example this is **Course** Object:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6019629588551e468c192570"
    },
    "title": "Course title",
    "tags": [{
        "$oid": "601a5f93aa5f525b605ff4c6"
    }, {
        "$oid": "6018233184946306306a2c76"
    }],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-02-02T14:32:53.111Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-02-04T13:28:30.348Z"
    },
}
```

And this is **CourseBlock** object:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6019629588551e468c192574"
    },
    "title": "New Block Title",
    "displayTitle": "New Block Title",
    "body": "",
    "_courseId": {
        "$oid": "6019629588551e468c192570"
    },
    "metaTags": [{
        "$oid": "601a502b572e8e04880ac944"
    }],
    "subjectTypes": [{
        "$oid": "601a50b3572e8e04880ac949"
    }],
}
```

I need to implement search functionality. The user will be able to enter course name. And also, user will be able to select additional **tag** objects for **course** and **course block** metatags and subjectTypes.

The pipeline:

```
[{$match: {
  title: / /i,
  tags: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $in: [ObjectId('601a5f93aa5f525b605ff4c6')]
      }
  }
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'blocks',
  "let":{"courseId":"$_id"},
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match:{
        $expr:{
          $eq:["$$courseId","$_courseId"],
        },


     },
    }
  ],
  as: 'blocks'
}}]
```

What I would need is to apply $elemMatch for blocks that belongs for target course.  in the $lookup block (pipeline).

How can I extend pipeline block to achieve this in a performant way?

Comment: in which field of collection blocks you want to match elemMatch condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good, this seems to do what is needed:

```
{
  from: 'blocks',
  "let":{"courseId":"$_id"},
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match:{
        $expr:{
          $eq:["$$courseId","$_courseId"],
        },
        eos: {
          $elemMatch: {
            $in: [ObjectId('601a502b572e8e04880ac944')]
          }
        },
        tos: {
          $elemMatch: {
            $in: [ObjectId('601a502b572e8e04880ac944')]
          }
        },
        klps: {
          $elemMatch: {
            $in: [ObjectId('601a502b572e8e04880ac944')]
          }
        }
        
      },
    }
  ],
  as: 'blocks'
}
```